# html form in php not sending to email from server

Tags: php, html

i have a form in my php page like the following:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <h1>Sign Up Now!
    <!-- <span>Sign up and tell us what you think of the site!</span> --></h1>
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <label>Your Full Name <input type="text" name="field1" /></label>
    <label>Address <textarea name="field2"></textarea></label>
  </div>




  <div class="button-section">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Sign Up" />

  </div>
</form>
```

the code for it is below:

```html
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $to = "zubairking@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['field1']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>
```

my server is also mail enabled, but this code of mine is not sending values to my mail, all the code is in one page, can anyone please tell me whats wrong with my code?  thanks in advance

Comment: Are you get any error while execute?. please check error enabled on your php ? And check spam folder of your to email address

Comment: I'm quite sure that `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` always return false, even after submitting the form, because nothing in your form has `name="submit"` in it. If you want, add an `else` clause, then submit the form again

Comment: And where do you get `$_POST['first_name']` or `$_POST['last_name'];` from?

Comment: "_$_POST['field1']; // this is the sender's Email address_" No it's not, your label says that field is `Your Full Name`

Comment: Is that the entire FORM or have you removed some elements for the benefit of the question somehow?

Comment: its not the entire form, its not about the field names, i am not able to get anything in my mail, atleast blank message

Comment: @CarlBinalla i added name="submit" still nothing happend

Comment: @SeepSooo Where did you add the name attribute? The submit button itself is not posted with the form nevertheless it had a name or not.

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant the submit button is already there in the question

Comment: Could you please fix the example so that it corresponds your real code better? This way we can point you only a ton of mistakes from the code, and you say "_it not like that in my real code_". Questions are not supposed to be a quiz game ...

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` should be `if(isset($_POST['Sign Up'])){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the submit button to have `name="submit"` for the condition `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` to be met. You also need to add elements with names='first_name', 'last_name' and 'message' in the form to apply them in your email messages as you are trying to do.
You also need your `<input type="text" name="field1" />` to be an email instead a name, given that you are using it to set the sender of the email.